# MariaDB RHEL Fresh Install Root Login Issue

Tags: mysql, redhat, mariadb, systemctl

I just installed MariaDB on a RHEL system and this is my first time using MariaDB.  I can start/stop the service only using the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
sudo systemctl enable mariadb.service 

sudo systemctl stop mariadb.service
```

Now, when I try to use the following:

```
mysql --user=root
```

I'm given the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Being a fresh install I would expect the password to be blank and I have uninstalled and reinstalled hoping that might resolve the issue but clearly it didn't.

I have read about using --skip-grant-tables to reset the password for root but I have been unable to start the service with this option in place given that I have to use systemctl.  I'm not sure if perhaps I'm putting the option in the wrong location in the command, but I have tried a number of methods to no avail.

No other commands (from /etc/init.d) work at all to get this service running.

If anyone can assist in helping me get the --skip-grant-tables working or to figure out how to somehow reset the root password for mariadb, or somehow set up another user with all privileges, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you quite certain that this is a fresh installation?

Comment: Yes, this is a fresh install.  Brand new server.  I installed once and ran into this issue and tried removing and installing once again and still the same issue presents itself.

Comment: OK, what did you forget to mention? Obviously something else is going on here.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that I don't actually have access to the root password itself (against IT practices to provide this to non-IT individuals, even though they were giving me this server to do with as I pleased).  The system was forcing the entry of the actual root password and would not work with a blank password.  Once the actual root pass was entered, it worked fine.  A user was created for myself to use and now it's working.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `mysql_secure_installation - improve MySQL installation security`, as Michael mention, it almost sounds like you already have `mysql` database with something other than fresh install.

You can also try stop `mariadb.service` delete mysql database and then try to give it another try with `mysql_install_db - initialize MySQL data directory`.

Comment: When running `mysql_secure_installation` it asks for the root password, which I haven't set. Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). Do you see the redundancy here?

Comment: @User use `-p` to enter your password (or hit enter/return if there isn't one)

Answer (score 1):

Try running the client as root.. It's likely that the default is unix socket auth for root, which checks if the UID of the process is the required UID for the user (in this case, 0) and allows/denies based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
`mysql --user=root -p`
and then when asked for the password, just pressing enter?

Sorry it this is obvious and you have, thought it worth a mention just in case.

Comment: I have and it still denies access, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you are running mysql_secure_installation as sudo if you dont have system root access or system root is disabled. I ran in this same problem before where I disabled root login systemwide and tried running mysql_secure_installation without sudo.

Comment: Are you certain that sudo is default enabled on RHEL-based systems?

Comment: that I am not too sure of, as when installing Debian, if you leave the password blank for root, it disables it and grants sudo to the user account created during the OS install . Regardless, just enable sudo for the non-root user account.